# right half-closed rectangles being complement of left half-closed

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding the Borel sigma-algebra. I was reading that the Borel sets sigma-algebra could be generated by right-half closed intervals, i.e. intervals of the form

$(a_i,b_i]$ which in turns can be written as a countable intersection of some open-intervals (which is not very relevant here): 
$(a_i,b_i] = \bigcap_{ i \in\mathbb{Z^+}} (a_i, b+1/i)$

My question is, I was reading that the left half-closed intervals (i.e. the intervals of the form  $[a_i, b_i)$ ) can also generated the Borel set, the argument that the author uses is that the Left half-closed intervals is complements of sets in the right half-closed intervals. My question is how. Could someone give some hints or explains?

Because say when I take the complement of a right half-closed intervals such as (-2, 3], I got $(-\infty, -2] \cup (3, \infty]$ which don't seem to be a Left half-closed interval.

Could someone give some explanations.

Thank you

Comment: They are countable unions of right closed intervals.

Comment: Hello Elliot, thanks for the response. But is it possible to know if it is possible to get the set of  left half closed interval by taking complement of sets in the right half closed interval? Because the author specifically says it can be done here : http://www.stat.colostate.edu/~estep/assets/chapter6.pdf. It is the very first line on page  6 of the PDF.

Comment: What you can do is something like $$[a,b)=\bigcup_{n\geq n_0}\bigcap_{m\geq m_0}
 (a-1/m,b-1/n]$$

Comment: Hello Filburt, very appreciate your response. But is it possible to know if it the Left half-closed intervals can be extracted from the set of Right half-closed intervals by taking complement of the set in the Right half-closed intervals? because the author says it can be done. The author says the Left half-closed intervals is complement of the set in the Right half-closed intervals.